# Kafka Server Not Starting on Windows 11: No Response or Error Messages

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to the Kafka world and I'm attempting to start the Kafka server on my Windows 11 Home machine by running the following command:

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties\
```

However, when I press Enter to execute the command (Zookeeper is up and running), nothing happens. The command prompt simply moves to the next line and awaits a new command.

Here's a screenshot confirming that Zookeeper is running:

[image]

And here is the command prompt for Kafka server:
[image]

As you can see, there is no response, error message, or informative output.

I've also monitored the server.log in the logs directory, but I couldn't find any information related to the kafka-server-start command. It appears that running the command didn't trigger any action, and consequently, no log file was created.

Comment: Kafka isn't really tested on windows. You can use WSL2. Plus, Zookeeper is no longer required